# Unable to build titanium android module with ant

Tags: android, ant, titanium, titanium-modules

I am trying to build module with ant. I am getting below error message.

```
BUILD FAILED
/Users/XXXX/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.4.1.GA/module/android/build.xml:163: /Users/XXXX/Documents/titanium-test-workspace/holograph/lib does not exist.
```

Path to module repo : [TiHoloGraph](http://github.com/railskarthi/TiHoloGraph)

Settings in my build.properties are

```
titanium.platform=/Users/XXXX/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.4.1.GA/android
android.platform=/Users/XXXX/Documents/android-sdk-macosx/platforms/android-19
google.apis=/Users/XXXX/Documents/android-sdk-macosx/add-ons/addon-google_apis-google-19
android.ndk=/Users/XXXX/Documents/android-ndk-r1
```

any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had the same problems with building modules.

Somehow ANT cannot create a lib folder in MacOS.

Just create a `/Users/XXXX/Documents/titanium-test-workspace/holograph/lib` folder yourself and you'll be fine